# Unable to listen to dragend event on div

Tags: javascript, draggable

I have a `div` where I simply want to listen to `dragend` event but for some reason, it's not working. I want to console log when the blue box gets dropped inside the rectangle but it's giving nothing...

**Here's the code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #a {
        width: 350px;
        height: 70px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; }
      #drag1 {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Drag the blue box into the rectangle and wait for the console log:</p>

    <div id="a"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="drag1" draggable="true"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    dropArea = document.getElementById("a");
    dragger = document.getElementById("drag1");
    dropArea.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
      console.log("Hello.....");
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dragend event is launch from element drag when you finish to drag it

you have to put the dragend event on drag element and not the drop area

change

```
dropArea.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
```

by

```
dragger.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
```

```js
    dropArea = document.getElementById("a");
    dragger = document.getElementById("drag1");
    dragger.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
      console.log("Here.....");
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #a {
        width: 350px;
        height: 70px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; }
      #drag1 {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Drag the blue box into the rectangle and wait for the console log:</p>

    <div id="a"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="drag1" draggable="true"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! but the thing is that I want to `console.log()` only when the item is `dragend` on that rectangle only. Currently, it spits out 'hello...' wherever it's `dragend`

Comment: Okay, I got it. We can do `if element classname == my target classname` Thanks!

Comment: great congratulation for your success ;) use the element class name is a good way to perform what you need